# How do you incorporate Apple scripts made in Script Editor with a Python project in PyCharm?

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, applescript

I am unsure of how, (or if you can) incorporate an existing Apple script made in macOS Script Editor into a Python project in PyCharm.

The AppleScript looks in a specific area of an app, and returns how long you've been doing a certain activity based on a set of GUI-based commands. That much is working as expected, but I want to use PyCharm to create an applet that displays said results in the menu bar.

Through a bit of research and asking around, it sounds like Subprocess Management is what I'll need to use, but I'm still new to Python, and don't want to go down that rabbit hole if it isn't what I need, or if there is an easier way.

Here's an example of the AppleScript:

---

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "App that I am using"
        set activityState to value of menu button 1 of group 1 of group 4 of toolbar 1 of window of application process "App that I am using" of application "System Events" as list
        return activityState as string
    end tell
end tell

---

As of now, I don't have any of the Python scripting done since I'm still unsure if what I want to do can be accomplished.

The Apple Script above is working as expected, other than a repeat forever statement that I have not added yet.

I have PyCharm 2019.1.3 and Python 3.7 installed on my Mac, but haven't attempted to write anything there since I'm new and unsure if this is something that can be done.

Comment: What language(s) _are_ you familiar with?  Note that AppleScriptObjC can be used to create status items, and a Python / Objective-C bridge is also available via the PyObjC framework.

Comment: Agree with @red_menace: this seems like something you could do entirely from AppleScriptObjC, without using python at all. Also, are you sure you want a menu item, and not a small floating status panel? The menu bar doesn't have a lot of room (at least mine doesn't), and for a task-specific display like this a panel might be more appropriate..